# Insert a row in a table with AUTOINCREMENT column

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE "INGREDIENTS" (
       "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
       "material" VARCHAR, 
       "type" VARCHAR, 
       "company" VARCHAR
 )
```

and I want to add a row

```
INSERT INTO "INGREDIENTS" VALUES('material1','type1','company1');
```

and I get an error, `... has 4 columns but 3 values supplied`

However, I want the row to get the id value +1 from the previous row ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify in which columns you insert

```
INSERT INTO INGREDIENTS (material, type, company) 
VALUES ('material1', 'type1', 'company1');
```

You should actually always specify the columns. If you don't and your table changes then your queries will start to break.